# react-native library not found for -lRNSVG-tvOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, mobile-development

I'm using react-native for developing android and ios app.
I know nothing about ios-development and Xcode environment.

When i run `react-native run-ios` i see this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lRNSVG-tvOS
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


** BUILD FAILED **
```

Any ideas?

**UPD**:
This might be caused by react-native-svg or react-native-vector-icons package.

Answer (score 0):

related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13783

Just removed *-tvOS.a file from libraries

From https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/issues/258#issuecomment-340434729:

> Seems like a bug caused by react-native link
>
> You can manually delete
> libRNDeviceInfo-tvOS.a in Xcode -> [Your iOS build target] -> Build
> Phrases -> Link Binary with Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

We had a multi target setup for multiple clients. This library was added to base target. Make sure to remove from correct target.